# lte & gte query inconsistent when Crosschecking for dates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want users to be able to check the calendar for dates already booked so the person won't be able to book a room if it has been booked already. I used the lte and gte to check for dates but it's very inconsistent.

See what my DB looks like below.

[image]

The main problem I'm facing,

From June 2 to June 13 have been booked for hotelroom id 1. It's returning available instead of not available.

```
>>> start_date='2016-06-02'
>>> end_date='2016-06-13'
>>>    check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date) | Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> if check_for_bookings:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
available
>>>
```

I selected from June 3 to June 14 and tested it with the below query and it worked. It showed that the room is not available.

```
>>> start_date='2016-06-03'
>>> end_date='2016-06-14'
>>> check_for_bookings=HotelCalendar.objects.filter(Q(checkin_booked_date__gte=start_date)|Q(checkout_booked_date__lte=end_date), hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> if check_for_bookings:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
not available
```

The question is why did the first query failed to return 'not available' when the dates have been booked.?

What other query can I run to make it efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions have been swapped `gte <> lte` . The second query worked because there is a matching date `'2016-06-14'` for `hotelrooms_id=1`.

But you want to check if `start_date` and `end_date` are within range `checkin_booked_date` to `checkout_booked_date`:

```
check_for_bookings = HotelCalendar.objects.filter(checkin_booked_date__lte=start_date, 
                                                  checkout_booked_date__gte=end_date,
                                                  hotelrooms_id=1)
```

Use `exists` if you only need to check and not fetch the objects:

```
if HotelCalendar.objects.filter(checkin_booked_date__lte=start_date,
                                checkout_booked_date__gte=end_date, 
                                hotelrooms_id=1).exists():
```

---

**Update:**

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/3125566), we can tell if start and end dates overlap with the dates of occupancy of a client:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

hotelcalendar = HotelCalendar.objects.filter(hotelrooms_id=1)

start_date = dt.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = dt.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

if hotelcalendar.checkin_booked_date <= end_date and hotelcalendar.checkout_booked_date >= start_date:
     print "not available"
else:
     print "available"
```

**Update:**

I tweaked it this way: I changed 'filter' to 'get' because it will return 'AttributeError'. And I used `datetime.date()` directly. And it worked fine so far!

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hotelcalendar= HotelCalendar.objects.get(hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> start_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 14)
>>> end_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 19)
>>> if hotelcalendar.checkin_booked_date <= end_date and hotelcalendar.checkout_booked_date >= start_date:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
not available

>>> hotelcalendar= HotelCalendar.objects.get(hotelrooms_id=1)
>>> start_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 15)
>>> end_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 19)
>>> if hotelcalendar.checkin_booked_date <= end_date and  hotelcalendar.checkout_booked_date >= start_date:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
available
>>> hotelcalendar= HotelCalendar.objects.get(hotelrooms_id=3)
>>> start_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 02)
>>> end_date= datetime.date(2016, 06, 10)
>>> if hotelcalendar.checkin_booked_date <= end_date and hotelcalendar.checkout_booked_date >= start_date:
...     print 'not available'
... else:
...     print 'available'
...
not available
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro.. It worked but when I set the start_date='2016-06-14' and end_date='2016-06-19', I got 'available'. I was thinking it should be 'not available' because ' start_date='2016-06-14' has been saved already in the calendar as checkout_date for hotelroom 1. What do you think?

Comment: Even for hotelroom_id 3, when I selected start_date= '2016-06-02', end_date='2016-06-10' I was able to book and that shouldn't be. What do you think?

Comment: Oops, I figured this would break with overlaps. I've added an update

Comment: You mean hotelcalendar.checkin_booked_date? Also I've tested it with the Q option and I even used | and & operators yet they failed.. | will work when checking already booked room and will fail when the room is free. The & operator is the same as your first answer.

Comment: Do the comparison in python. I found a post that can help detect overlaps. See updates

Comment: Bro thanks! I've updated your answer and marked it. Now the question is, since the user will input the date directly in the field like '2016-06-04' do I need to convert the date to (2016, 06, 04) and use datetime.date(user_input_date) before I can compare or Django wil take care of it itself?

Comment: Glad it worked. You'll need to convert it. But you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-06-04', '%Y-%m-%d')` to convert from the string format into a `datetime` object.

Comment: Don't you think the conversion will be long.. like after converting to datetime object, I will have to change the format to (2016, 06, 04)?

Comment: You can use the `datetime` object directly without further need for changes

Comment: You know what bro.. I just tried it directly without converting and it worked! Thanks for the support! You rock.